# Memory issues with linked list's constructor, destructor and copy constructor

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, valgrind, destructor

My Teacher told me I have problems with memory, and I think it's destructor and copy constructor's fault but I can't find the problem. Here's parte of my code and report from valgrind.

````
struct Board 
{
    string s;
    Board* next;
    Board* prev;
};
typedef Board* Pboard;

struct Player::Impl
{
    Pboard head;
    Pboard tail;
    int player;
    void destroy(Pboard head);
};

void Player::Impl::destroy(Pboard head)
{
    if (head) {
        destroy(head->next);
        delete head;
    }
}

Player::Player(int player_nr)
{
    if (player_nr != 1 && player_nr != 2) throw player_exception{ (player_exception::err_type::index_out_of_bounds), "Giocatore non definito"};
    pimpl = new Impl;
    pimpl->player = player_nr;
    pimpl->head = nullptr;
    pimpl->tail = nullptr;
}

Player::~Player()
{
    pimpl->destroy(pimpl->head);
    delete pimpl;
}

Player::Player(const Player& source)
{
    pimpl = new Impl;
    pimpl = source.pimpl;
}

Player& Player::operator=(const Player& s)
{
    if (s.pimpl->head == nullptr) {
        pimpl->head = nullptr;
        pimpl->tail = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        pimpl->destroy(pimpl->head);
        pimpl->head = nullptr;
        pimpl->tail = nullptr;
        Pboard pb = s.pimpl->head;
        pimpl->player = s.pimpl->player;
        while (pb) {
            Pboard pboard = new Board;
            pboard->next = nullptr;
            pboard->s = pb->s;
            pboard->prev = pimpl->tail;
            if (pimpl->tail != nullptr)
                pimpl->tail->next = pboard;
            else
                pimpl->head = pboard;
            pimpl->tail = pboard;
            pb = pb->next;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}```
````

I tried various solutions but I dont really know if it works bc he won't let me see his main, I have to use my own.  Here's the report from valgrind he sent me.

```
==235== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==235== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==235== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==235== Command: ../consegne/prova_decompressed/890361/benchmark /home/nico/progetti_PEL/scripts/testcase
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x1178E0: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dc8a20 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117906: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:39)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117847: Player::Player(int) (player_filt.cpp:30)
==235==    by 0x10CB39: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x117778: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcae10 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CB69: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:133)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x117778: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcd270 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CBA5: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:134)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x117778: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcf6d0 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CBE1: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:135)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x499D5C4: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcf6b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CBE1: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:135)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcf720 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 51 free'd
==235==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x499D29E: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x499D5FD: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x11801D: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:121)
==235==    by 0x10CBE1: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:135)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcf6b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CBE1: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:135)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcd250 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x11778A: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:22)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CBA5: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:134)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x499D5C4: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcadf0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CB69: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:133)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcae60 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 54 free'd
==235==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x11B7DB: Board::~Board() (player_filt.cpp:3)
==235==    by 0x11779B: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x499D29E: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x499D5FD: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x11801D: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:121)
==235==    by 0x10CB69: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:133)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dcadf0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x1177A8: Player::Impl::destroy(Board*) (player_filt.cpp:23)
==235==    by 0x1178ED: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:38)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117FE3: Player::load_board(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (player_filt.cpp:119)
==235==    by 0x10CB69: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:133)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117906: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:39)
==235==    by 0x10CDC2: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Address 0x4dc8a20 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==235==    at 0x483D1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117906: Player::~Player() (player_filt.cpp:39)
==235==    by 0x10CDB3: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235==  Block was alloc'd at
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117847: Player::Player(int) (player_filt.cpp:30)
==235==    by 0x10CB39: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:132)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== Invalid read of size 8
==235==    at 0x499FC08: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x117C0D: Player::operator()(int, int, int) const (player_filt.cpp:91)
==235==    by 0x110A10: check_access2(double) (benchmark.cpp:504)
==235==    by 0x116916: main (benchmark.cpp:1004)
==235==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==235== 
==235== 
==235== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==235==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==235==    at 0x499FC08: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==235==    by 0x117C0D: Player::operator()(int, int, int) const (player_filt.cpp:91)
==235==    by 0x110A10: check_access2(double) (benchmark.cpp:504)
==235==    by 0x116916: main (benchmark.cpp:1004)
==235==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==235==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==235==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==235==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==235==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==235== 
==235== HEAP SUMMARY:
==235==     in use at exit: 188 bytes in 5 blocks
==235==   total heap usage: 2,470 allocs, 2,472 frees, 6,973,158 bytes allocated
==235== 
==235== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 5
==235==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==235==    by 0x117927: Player::Player(Player const&) (player_filt.cpp:44)
==235==    by 0x10CC06: check_copy_constr(double) (benchmark.cpp:137)
==235==    by 0x1168B9: main (benchmark.cpp:1001)
==235== 
==235== LEAK SUMMARY:
==235==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==235==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==235==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==235==    still reachable: 164 bytes in 4 blocks
==235==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==235== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==235== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==235== 
==235== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==235== ERROR SUMMARY: 16 errors from 14 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
STDERR.txt
Visualizzazione di STDERR.txt.
```

Comment: Without reading anything but the title, my money's on [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation. Well shoot. There's the skeleton of it. I guess I'll have to look deeper.

Comment: step 1: remove types like `typedef Board* Pboard;` - you've just hidden from me that we're dealing with pointers which makes the code twice as hard to decipher.

Comment: player's copy constructor is wrong. You create a new pointer, assign it to your variable, then immediately tell that variable to point to somewhere else. That's a memory leak... Which then causes UB when either player is deleted.

Comment: `Impl` also looks like it may need some copying smarts.

Answer (score 1):

Player's copy constructor is wrong. You create a new pointer, assign it to your variable, then immediately tell that variable to point to somewhere else. That's a memory leak... Which then causes UB when either player is deleted.

```
Player::Player(const Player& source)
{
    pimpl = new Impl; // dynamical allocation, assign to variable 
    pimpl = source.pimpl; // now changing where the pointer points to. Memory leak.
    // Both players also now point to the same memory location, so the destructor really causes issues. 
}
```

Comment: Canonically it should look something like `pimpl = new Impl(source.pimpl);`, but to do that `Impl` needs to be safe to copy and that means `Board` needs to be safe to copy. So the better idea is to uncouple all of this and separate out the linked list.

Comment: @user4581301, agreed. Probably better to just use `std::list` or similar, really. Can also probably avoid pointers for the board as well.

Comment: Agree on `std::list`, but the question reads like a "Make a linked list." homework assignment